# Can exceptions be "duplicated" via exception pointers?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

For some multithreaded code, I would like to capture all exceptions and pass a them to a single exception handling thread. Here's the message passing framework:

```
#include <exception>

struct message
{
    virtual ~message() = default;
    virtual void act() = 0;
};

struct exception_message : message
{
    std::exception_ptr ep;

    virtual void act()
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(ep);
    }

    // ...
};
```

Here's the use case:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (...)
{
    exception_message em { std::current_exception(); }
    handler_thread.post_message(em);
}
```

The handler thread goes through all its messages and calls `act()`, and it can install its own try/catch block to handle all the posted exceptions.

Now I was wondering what happens if I send copies this message to multiple receivers. In general, mes­sa­ges may have any number of recipients, and so I don't want to put arbitrary restrictions on exception pro­pa­ga­tion messages. The `exception_ptr` is documented as a "shared-ownership" smart pointer, and `rethrow_exception` "does not introduce a data race".

So my question: Is it legitimate to duplicate an active exception by storing it in an `exception_ptr`, copy­ing the pointer, and calling `rethrow_exception` multiple times?

Comment: just find by google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293602.aspx  "Transporting Exceptions Between Threads"

Comment: Never tried anything like that.  Copying/communicating an exception to another thread and re-raising it there sounds a bit strange since the exception, once received, has lost all its context re. the original thread except in so far as what it contains itself.  Inspecting the signaled exceptiion in one thread, and maybe logging it or whatever, I could understand.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: That page isn't C++. There's no `std::copy_exception` in C++,

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually `"std::"copy_exception` means `std::make_exception_ptr` in standard C++.

Comment: @KennyTM: I know, I know... but it has nothing to do with my question. It's just a terribly unfortunate name, that's already claimed its first victim here.

Comment: @KerrekSB - granted, that page is Windows-intensive (and it's interesting that Microsoft claims credit for implementing pretty much what the C++ standard requires), but `copy_exception` is the name in earlier drafts of C++11 for `make_exception_ptr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding of the Standard, it is legitimate. However I would note that the rethrow *does not duplicate* the exception, and therefore the shared exception object itself is submitted to data races should you modify it and access it from other threads meantime. If the exception is read-only (once thrown), then you should not have any issue.

Regarding storage duration:

> **15.1 Throwing an exception [except.throw]**
>
> *4* The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified way, except as noted in 3.7.4.1. If a handler exits by rethrowing, control is passed to another handler for the same exception. The exception object is destroyed after either the last remaining active handler for the exception exits by any means other than rethrowing, or the last object of type `std::exception_ptr` (18.8.5) that refers to the exception object is
>   destroyed, whichever is later. In the former case, the destruction occurs when the handler exits, immediately after the destruction of the object declared in the exception-declaration in the handler, if any. In the latter case, the destruction occurs before the destructor of `std::exception_ptr` returns.

Regarding data races:

> **18.8.5 Exception propagation [propagation]**
>
> *7* For purposes of determining the presence of a data race, operations on `exception_ptr` objects shall access and modify only the `exception_ptr` objects themselves and not the exceptions they refer to. Use of `rethrow_exception` on `exception_ptr` objects that refer to the same exception object shall not introduce a data race. [ Note: if `rethrow_exception` rethrows the same exception object (rather than a copy), concurrent access to that rethrown exception object may introduce a data race. Changes in the number of `exception_ptr` objects that refer to a particular exception do not introduce a data
>   race. —end note ]

Regarding `rethrow`:

> `[[noreturn]] void rethrow_exception(exception_ptr p);`
>
> *9 Requires*: `p` shall not be a null pointer.
>
> *10 Throws*: the exception object to which p refers.

Comment: I read that, too, but what does it mean? Is the actual, *same* exception object thrown multiple times? Is that OK? Does that even mean anything?

Comment: @KerrekSB: What does `thrown` mean ? `throw` is just a goto/jump within the context of a thread that happen to respect stack unwinding. Therefore it poses no problem to `rethrow` the exact same object several times, the object itself can be seen as directing the jump (toward the right `catch` clause).

Comment: @KerrekSB - I just went through the same exercise, and I don't think there's anything that says whether multiple rethrows of copies of the same `exception_ptr` object throw distinct copies of the underlying exception. The implication of "if `rethrow_exception` rethrows the same exception object (rather than a copy)..." is that either is allowed. In practice, I don't think it matters much; catching an exception by reference and modifying its contents is just plain weird, and that's pretty much the only way you'd run into varying behavior depending on whether the exception is copied.

Comment: The issue isn't whether rethrowing the same object could create a problem; it's determining what behavior you can count on.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I could not determine it, the only thing I could find concerns `current_exception`: *[ Note: That is, it is unspecified whether `current_exception` creates a new copy each time it is called. —end note ]* and makes me think that whether `rethrow` copies or not depends on the actual implementation.

Comment: I agree, but there are two separate questions here: first, whether two calls to `current_exception` get pointers that refer to distinct objects; second, whether `rethrow_exception` copies the exception object. In both cases, I think the answer is that it's unspecified.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: OK, we're definitely only calling `current_exception` once. That much should be assumed. And from "shared ownership" I gather that there is only ever *one* object.

Comment: @PeteBecker: the specification of `rethrow` is that the exception object is rethrown. Since in the case of the `throw` statement, the fact that a copy/move occurs is explicitly specified, I would understand this as meaning that no copy occurs in `rethrow`.

Comment: Pete is correct.  `rethrow_exception` is allowed but not required to throw a copy of the exception.  The Itanium ABI provides no capability to make a copy of the exception at this point.  Several vendors follow this ABI including gcc/Linux and Apple.  IIRC, Microsoft does make a copy at `rethrow_exception`, but I'm less sure of this latter statement.  In any event, both approaches are conforming.